# How to animate height change of views inside a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am working on an Android 4+ app which uses a quite simply layout: Multiple views are stacked using a `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UseCompoundDrawables,UselessParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 

        <!-- Top Container -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 

            <Button... />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Hidden Container -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 

            ... Some Content ...

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Bottom Container -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 

            ... Some Content ...

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The `HiddenContainer` should not be visible when the layout it created. Thus in the beginning the `BottomContainer` is directly beneath the `TopContainer`. A click on the `Button` within the `TopContainer` toggles the visibility of the `HiddenContainer`.

Doing this with `hiddenContainer.setVisibility(hiddenContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE)` works find and without any problem. However it does not look good when the view suddenly appears or disappears. **Instead I would like to animate the change.**

I was surprised that I was not able to find an easy solution for this:

- Using `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` does work, however I am not able to control the animation.
- While using a `ValueAnimator` to change `hiddenContainer.setScaleY(...)` gives me control over the animation `setScaleY(0)` makes the container invisible without reducing the space it occupies within the layout.
- Using the `ValueAnimator` to change `hiddenContainer.setHeight(...)` might work, however I don't want to use a fixed height value when showing the container (e.g. `hiddenContainer.setHeight(300)`) but the height which is determined by the containers content.

**So, how to solve this?**

Answer (score 3):

For animate your changes of layout (alpha, visibility, height, etc) you can use TransitionManager. For example: I have three static methods and use them when I want to animate layout changes:

```
public static final int DURATION = 200;

public static void beginAuto(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    AutoTransition transition = new AutoTransition();
    transition.setDuration(DURATION);
    transition.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewGroup, transition);
}

public static void beginFade(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Fade transition = new Fade();
    transition.setDuration(DURATION);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewGroup, transition);
}

public static void beginChangeBounds(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
    transition.setDuration(DURATION);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewGroup, transition);
}
```

And when you want to animate layout changes you can just call one of this methods before layout changings:

```
beginAuto(hiddenContainerParentLayout);
hiddenContainer.setVisibility(hiddenContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works pretty well. However when hiding the view the scroll "collapses" immediately and not animated. Assume that the ScrollView currently shows the ToggleButton and the complete `HiddenContainer`. So the ToggleButton would be at the top of the screen. When hiding the `HiddenContainer` the buttom "jumps" to the bottom of the screen (since the scroll content does not fill the entire screen any more) and on can see how the bottom view animates towards the top view. So while the animation works fine, the size change of the scroll content happens immediately.

Comment: In this case you should call beginAuto for root layout of ScrollView, with this solusition when you change visibility of HiddenContainer animator also animate changing coordinates of BottomContainer in ScrollView

Comment: As shown in my post ScrollView is the root layout. Even when I add another layout to wrap ScrollView and apply beginAuto to this one, the result is absolutely the same.

Comment: You can try using beginChangeBounds instead of beginAuto, or call beginAuto for parent of ScrollView (or for root layout). I hope one of this solutions help you.

Comment: The transition type (auto, fade, changeBound, etc.) does not make any difference. As explained ScrollView IS the root layout (has no parent) and adding a parent also makes no difference.